# C# read line from string

Tags: c#

How can I read all line from string.

My code that I have tested(Not working)

```
string line;
line = mycontent;
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(line);
string data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(data);
```

This code is showing error.
I want to create a simple program that can ReadToEnd from a string not from a file path. I have learned that StreamReader can be used for read a file from file path.

My intention is like i have a `string mycontent = "Simple"` and I want to read this `mycontent` to the end. But the `mycontent` is changing every times did I press a button. `So I want to create something that similar to this code.`

Thank you.

PS. The error says `'Illegal characters in path.'`

Comment: You want a StringReader, not a StreamReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [StreamReader constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_) takes a path as argument, not the literal string.

Use a [StringReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead. And for reading line by line, use the [`ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

Comment: @Fair: I think this has happened to all of us. I dislike the C# API a bit. They should have used a `FileInfo` parameter instead of a string. That would be much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `StringReader()` to read a string line by line:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(multilinestring);
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //do what you want to do with the line;
};
```